# Sliding jquery form is not transitioning more than one time

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I have created a sliding form with jquery that slides to the next layout perfectly fine, but its when I want it to slide back that it becomes a problem. The url in question is [here](http://www.entrilab.com)
and I know the problem is in the padding. Or am I not seeing something that I should be seeing?

```
#steps form fieldset{
    border:none;
    padding: 0 0 20px 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I'm having a hard time wrap my mind around what tweaks I need to make to get it going. Any tips will be greatly appreciated

Comment: just doing a quick firebug, i see that margin-left is being set to 0px as against margin-left: 600px. Can you do a check on what widths[] are being set as?

Comment: If I'm understanding the question correctly, the widths are being set at 600. Are you saying my margin-left needs to be changed? @karthikr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like its a jquery bug which has been addressed in 1.8.2. Simply replace

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Working example here http://jsfiddle.net/pimlinders/SWQRj/